# Mongoose: create the same subdocument in multiple places

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a chat structure that holds both, all messages and last message in one parent document (`chat`). When the user sends a message, I need to update `last_message` and append the new message to `messages` array. Is it possible to do in a single update oparation so `_id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` will be the same in both sub-documents?

Here is my attempt that doesn't work:

```js
const message = {
      content: req.body.contentg,
      sender: sender.toObject(),
};
const chat = await Chat.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: toObjectId(req.params.chat_id),
  status: 'active',
 }, {
  last_message: message,
  $push: { messages: message },
}, {
  new: true,
});
```

**Update:** Added schemas (I'm using ts-mongoose)

```
export const MessageSenderSchema = createSchema({
    last_name: Type.string(),
    first_name: Type.string(),
    phone: Type.string({ required: true }),
    email: Type.string(),
    status: Type.string({ enum: UserStatuses, required: true }),
}, {
    skipVersioning: true,
});

export const ChatMessageSchema = createSchema({
    content: Type.string({ required: true }),
    status: Type.string({ enum: ChatMessageStatuses, default: 'new' }),
    sender: Type.schema({ require: true }).of(MessageSenderSchema),
});
ChatMessageSchema.set('timestamps', { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' });

export const ChatSchema = createSchema({
    __v: Type.number({ select: false }),
    status: Type.string({ enum: ChatStatuses, default: 'active', required: true }),
    members: Type.array().of({
        $ref: Type.string(),
        $id: Type.objectId(),
        $db: Type.string({ required: false }),
    }),
    messages: Type.array().of(ChatMessageSchema),
    last_message: Type.schema().of(ChatMessageSchema),
});
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg, please add the chat schema structure

Comment: @PrasathBV added

Comment: Chat..findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: toObjectId(req.params.chat_id),
  status: 'active',
 },
{$push:{messages :m}},{$set:{lastmessage:m}},
 {
  new: true,
});

Comment: Hi @Oleg, while updating a document, for fields which is other than array,you have to use $set operator, for array fields use $push operator. Both should pass as different parms in findOneAndUpdate function.